# SAS how do i retrieve a list of datasets that are prefixed with a certain string

Tags: sas, dataset

in sas, I have a bunch of datasets in one of my libraries

i.e:

```
tmp_dataset_a
tmp_dataset_b
tmp_dataset_c
tmp_dataset_d
dataset1
dataset2
```

How do I extract a list of the datasets prefixed with tmp ?
I would like to store this list so I can access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SASHElP.VTABLE dictionary table. It stores metadata about the SAS tables, including names.

```
data want;
set sashelp.vtable;
where memname like 'tmp%';
run;
```